# ERROR 79018 --- [ main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I got some error on my spring boot project, I couldn't find what the problems is, can someone help me, these are my logs:

```
2020-11-30 23:23:20.804 ERROR 79018 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.qi.MySpringBoot1Application.main(MySpringBoot1Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:224) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:176) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:83) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

This is my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.qi</groupId>
    <artifactId>mySpringBoot-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mySpringBoot-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my controller:

```java
package com.qi.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.qi.models.AppUsers;
import com.qi.models.UsersRepo;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    UsersRepo appRepo;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView doHome() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        mv.addObject("lists",appRepo.findAll());
        return mv;
    }
    @RequestMapping( value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doSave(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("firstname") String firstName, @RequestParam("lastname") String lastName) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
        AppUsers users;
        if (!id.isEmpty()) {
            users = (AppUsers)appRepo.findById(Integer.parseInt(id)).orElse(null);
        } else {
            users = new AppUsers();
        }
        users.setFirstName(firstName);
        users.setLastName(lastName);
        appRepo.save(users);
        return mv;
    }
    @RequestMapping( value = "/view{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doView(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("view");
        mv.addObject("lists", appRepo.findById(id).get());
        return mv;
    }
    @RequestMapping( value = "/delete{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doDelete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
        appRepo.deleteById(id);
        return mv;
    }
    @RequestMapping( value = "/edit{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doEdit(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("edit");
        mv.addObject("lists", appRepo.findById(id).get());
        return mv;
    }

}
```

this is my model:

```java
package com.qi.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Entity
@Table(name = "appusers")
public class AppUsers {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;
    
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    public String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    public String lastName;
    

    public AppUsers() {
        
    }
    
    public AppUsers(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

This is my Repository:

```java
package com.qi.models;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UsersRepo extends CrudRepository<AppUsers, Integer>{


}
```

This is application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/qi 
spring.datasource.username=root 
spring.datasource.password= 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
#spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true 
server.port=8097
```

This is the main class:

```java
package com.qi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBoot1Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBoot1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your application jar is executed independently, please romove "runtime" of mysql in pom.xml.

Comment: @jacky-neo `runtime` scope should be fine.

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" Check your .m2 repository to ensure the file was downloaded.

Comment: Remove the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=` as it points to the wrong class and Spring Boot can figure it out itself.